# Searchspring widget created mulitple time in pwa site

Tags: angular-pwa

When we have implement searchspring js based soultion one of my project, we faced issue update bundle.js based on view page that searchspring bundle.js we change parameters but it create issue add duplicate same widget add into our site

Duplication widget need remove